# gdalwarp tiff reprojection from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I have a geoTiff file with the following gdalinfo output:

`Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: original.tif
Size is 48377, 15906
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (25.668509000000000,42.104685623790893)
Pixel Size = (0.000395841574135,-0.000395841574135)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  25.6685090,  42.1046856) ( 25d40' 6.63"E, 42d 6'16.87"N)
Lower Left  (  25.6685090,  35.8084295) ( 25d40' 6.63"E, 35d48'30.35"N)
Upper Right (  44.8181368,  42.1046856) ( 44d49' 5.29"E, 42d 6'16.87"N)
Lower Right (  44.8181368,  35.8084295) ( 44d49' 5.29"E, 35d48'30.35"N)
Center      (  35.2433229,  38.9565576) ( 35d14'35.96"E, 38d57'23.61"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=15
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=4`

I want to reproject it to EPSG:3857 for native (fast) rendering on Geoserver.
This is the command I use to reproject it:

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co 'TILED=YES' -co 'BLOCKXSIZE=256' -co 'BLOCKYSIZE=256' -ts 48377 15906 original.tif projected.tif`

Below, you can see the original, projected and both tiffs on top of each other:

#### Original:

[image: Original]

#### Projected:

[image: Projected]

#### Both:

[image: Both together]

As you can see the projected raster is not aligned with the original one.

I have read that `tap`can be used to align pixels, and tried this:

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co 'TILED=YES' -co 'BLOCKXSIZE=256' -co 'BLOCKYSIZE=256' -tap -tr 8 8 original.tif projected.tif`

Now this outputs a tiff file with a very little shift (about 2m) which I am ok with. But the processing is very slow and the resulting file is 30GB.

Giving large tr values such as `-tr 40 40`, fixes the slow processing problem, but the output tiles are no longer have the same value as the original ones because of the resampling I guess.

I also want to note that, tiles from the above picture are requested using EPSG:3857 srs from Geoserver. Geoserver can project native EPSG:4326 tiles to EPSG:3857 on the fly with accurate precision, but I can not produce the same result with gdal.

**EDIT**

These are some screenshots for different target resolutions:

#### `-tr 20 20`

[image]

#### `-tr 30 30`

[image]

#### `-tr 8 8`

[image]

#### `-tr 7.0832868662 7.0832868662`

[image]

Comment: the output file is bigger because you haven't used any compression -co COMPRESS=LZW should help

Comment: I can use LZW however it reduces the performance of geoserver's tile rendering, that's why I haven't used that. The reason I am reprojecting the data to another projection is to improve Geoserver's rendering time.

Comment: for a 30gb file compression will help more than it hinders, also add overviews

Comment: Try also `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co 'TILED=YES' -co 'BLOCKXSIZE=256' -co 'BLOCKYSIZE=256' original.tif projected.tif`without target size. See if pixels are shifted and tell us what is the pixel size when GDAL can decide it.

Comment: @iant According to this slide http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/gs-steroids-sgiannecfoss4g20130103/17 there is significant (70%) performance loss. Are you sure it will help?

Comment: I was looking at the 2015 slides -https://image.slidesharecdn.com/gssteroidsaaimefoss4g2015-150921072827-lva1-app6891/95/geoserver-on-steroids-foss4g-2015-8-638.jpg?cb=1442821235

Comment: only way to be sure is to experiment

Comment: @user30184 without target size pixels are not only shifted but the resulting shapes are wider and shorter. Pixel size is 45.456323941454777,-45.456323941454777 (in EPSG:3857 units).. Size is 46896, 19852. With target size (ts),  pixel size is 44.064736704600612,-56.733241725497308 (in EPSG:3857 units).

Comment: Suggestion: use DEFLATE instead of LZW, it should be faster

Comment: @AndreaAime thank you very much for your suggestion. I am very curious, how does geoserver/qgis does it on the fly so fast and without shifting and destorting? They must be doing the same thing when converting native 4326 tiles to 3857 tiles, right?

Comment: Gdalwarp makes by default square pixels. It is OK to force them non-squere as you do with your -ts parameter. But your -tap -tr 8 8 makes heavy oversampling and makes file unnecessary big as you have noticed.

Comment: @nilgun I don't know what QGIS does, but GeoServer does it fast because most of the time the transformation can be assimilated to a simple scale (with different factors in x and y) without visible loss of accuracy. The complete trigonometric math is used only if the area being displayed is very large (low zoom levels)

Comment: @iant You were right, epsg:3857 float32 image with compression, renders so much faster than epsg:4326 float32 image without compression in my case.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is measure the size of your original pixels in your target SRS, and make your target resolution a multiple of those. (You'll need to pick something that works for most of the area, as it will change at high latitudes).

Otherwise, your testing with 8 x 8 sounds like it worked ok, so experiment with compression to get the file size right.

And finally, you could just rely on GeoServer and use GeoWebCache to convert it for you. This will result in something fast, as is what you want to be using anyway in production. So, even if you do optimise your source data, allowing GWC to pre-cache or cache on demand should make it as good as possible.

EDIT:

What's going on here is that your TARGET raster is not going to be aligned with your SOURCE raster. As you note, using a low resolution target means that the error in alignment is small, but it't not perfect. This is a fundamental fact of the two grids you're making, in two quite different coordinate reference systems, and unless you make your grid very small, you'll always have errors. (And unless that small grid lines up perfectly with every cell of the source, it'll still have errors, really, they'll just be small...)

Something to ask is: how accurate is your data. You're mapping at a ~50 m grid, recall, so it's not going to be very accurate, and is certainly not all that precise. A target grid that lines up within maybe 10%, or 5 m, could be acceptable. But that's up to you.

Looking at your images, the 20 m and 30 m grids line up good enough, in my view. It's not a systematic error, i.e., you've got errors in all different directions.

Comment: Original pixel size is (0.000395841574135,-0.000395841574135). I am using a linestring from the center of the tif to calculate size of original pixels in 3857 as follows: `SELECT ST_Length( ST_Transform( ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(35.2433229 38.9565576,35.2433229 38.9569534416)'), 3857 ) );`. This yields 56.6662949295714. Since you suggested multiples, I divided this number by 8 and used `-tr 7.0832868662 7.0832868662`. The result is not as close (to the original 4326 on the fly projected result) as `-tr 8 8`.

Comment: Do I need to manually check all my other files (there are like 30 more) to find out 8 8 works ok?

Comment: I am already using GeoWebCache. But for high zoom levels (where it does not hit the cache) it takes like 18-25 seconds for geoserver to create tiles from my rasters with Type:Float32 with native:4326 srs, requested with srs:3857 from leaflet.

Comment: If the size is around 56, I was thinking you could use, say, 20 (around 1/3) or maybe 30. The problem, I think, is that with a cell size of 56, and cells not lining up perfectly, your max error is pretty big. You can lower it by using smaller cells, but perhaps 8 is too small...

Comment: I edited the question with screenshots for different tr values.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer with some thoughts.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much, I really appreciate your answers. One last thing so that I can move on with this subject: "While geoserver/qgis can reproject raster data on the fly seemingly perfect, why we can not achieve the same quality with gdal?"

Comment: Hey @nilgun, I reckon that GeoServer is rendering these at a very high resolution, compared with what you're doing. The pixels that GeoServer renders at end up being the same as your -tr flag, so if it's doing a very zoomed in image, the -tr might be 0.01 m, say, and in that case, it'll line up very well!